# Cannot post using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, post

(UPDATE) I fixed the problem thanks to many people in the comments, now I have a new problem. I can't seem to redirect to the main page after saving the data. I get stuck at an intermidiate HTML that shows me the JSON sentence of what was saved.

I have been trying to use an html form to post information into an API but I always get the error **Cannot POST /**. I have tried many YouTube tutorials and examples I have seen on GitHub but I just can't seem to make it work. The following is the code that I have been using. Is there anything I'm doing wrong or not seeing ?

this is the **server.js** (though I don't think the problem is coming from here):

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
 
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
const db = mongoose.connection
db.on('error', (error) =>  console.error(error))
db.once('open', () => console.log('connected to database'))
 
app.use(express.json())
const jugadorRouter = require('./routes/jugadores')
app.use('/jugadores', jugadorRouter)
 
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

this is the **index** where the form is located:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="/">
<div class="form-control">
  <label for="username">Usuario</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Ingrese su usuario..." required />
</div>
<div class="form-control">
  <label for="room">Equipo</label>
  <select name="room" id="room">
    <option value="rojo">Equipo rojo</option>
    <option value="amarillo">Equipo Amarillo</option>
    <option value="blanco">Equipo Blanco</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button id="login" type="submit" class="btn" onclick="javascript: form.action='Gerente.html'" formmethod="post">Gerente</button>                
</form>
```

This is **jugadores.js** where the post method is located:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const Jugador = require('../model/jugador')
 
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
 console.log(req.body);
 const jugador = new Jugador({
  username: req.body.username,
  room: req.body.room
})
try{
  const newJugador = await jugador.save()
  res.status(201).json(newJugador)
}catch(err){
  res.status(400).json({message: err.message})
}
res.render('public/Gerente', {
  username: username,
  room: room
});
res.end();
});
 
module.exports = router
```

This is my **jugador.js**:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
//login schema
const jugadorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username:{
 type: String,
required: true
},
Date:{
type: Date,
required: true,
default: Date.now
}
})
 
module.exports = mongoose.model('Jugador', jugadorSchema);
```

Comment: What URL are you opening in your browser?

Comment: I'm running it on localhost:3000 so as soon as it runs the index.html loads up.

Comment: So it's `http://localhost:3000/`?

Comment: yeah thats right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original answer**

**1.** You have specified to use `/jugadores` before every api route in server.js (`app.use('/jugadores', jugadorRouter)`)  so in `Html` page your action will look like below

**html**

```html
 <form name="form" method="post" action="/jugadores/">
```

and Your api call will look like this  `http://localhost:3000/jugadores/` if you want use this code the changes will be done in your html form

And

**2.** If you want use only `/` in your route than remove `/jugadores` from `app.use('/jugadores', jugadorRouter)` so in `Html` page your action will look like below

**html**

```html
 <form name="form" method="post" action="/">
```

**server.js**

```js
  app.use(jugadorRouter)
```

and Your api call will look like this  `http://localhost:3000/`  if you want use this code the changes will be done in your server.js file

**Update**

As mentioned by you in comment that you are getting error

> {"message":"Jugador validation failed: username: Path username is required., room: Path room is required."}

To receive POST values in Express, you first need to include the `body-parser` middleware, which exposes submitted form values on `req.body` in your route handlers. As mentioned in this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/forms-file-uploads-security-node-express/)

First install [**body-parser**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

in `server.js`

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

Comment: or you could change the use statement to `app.use('/', jugadorRouter)` if you want to serve that route at `/`

Comment: No, If he want to use only `/` than he has to do `app.use(jugadorRouter)` if he use `app.use('/', jugadorRouter)` than request url will look like this `http://localhost:3000//`

Comment: I tried both of your recomendations but I get this message now: {"message":"Jugador validation failed: username: Path `username` is required., room: Path `room` is required."}

Comment: that means your api is working with that route but api is not getting any data from html form you have specified `required: true` in your model so it will throw error like this it means there is problem in your html form because it is not sending data in request to api

Comment: @andres now apply the changes I have updated in answer and it will work

Comment: yes, it works now. you have no idea how long i've been killing my head with this, thaks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

As your server is setup, your POST route is `/jugadores`.

So the form should be:

`<form name="form" method="post" action="/jugadores">`

And the button should not have `onclick` or `formmethod`, like:

`<button id="login" type="submit" class="btn">Gerente</button>`

Also, so that the server can handle forms add:

`app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))`

Comment: I tried what you said and got this: {"message":"Jugador validation failed: username: Path `username` is required., room: Path `room` is required."}

Comment: Great! So now you can reach your express route, but it is only setup to handle json body (like when you call it via the javascript `fetch` function). Check this post about [Handling forms in Express](https://flaviocopes.com/express-forms/). `app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))` should fix that.

Comment: Is it best to use bodyparser direct

Answer (score 2):

**1. What does the error mean?**

- while creating express server, you register a list of route handlers. The error `Cannot POST /` means *express can not find the registration of POST for route /*.

**2. What is the current situation?**

- after completed, the form submission send the POST request to route /
- express searchs for its route registration list. It can't find route handle for `POST /` request. So it yells error

**3. How to fix it?**

- when you declare a router handler like this `app.use('/jugadores', jugadorRouter)`, the path of the router handlers will be prefixed with `/jugadores`. Therefore, the `POST /` in jugadores.js will actually become `POST /jugadores`
- the only route handle express has for now is `POST /jugadores`. Seems like the form submission should be handled here. So you can change the html form action value like this

```html
<form name="form" method="post" action="/jugadores">
```

Thanks for the reading!